# Order of route precedence express 3 vs 4

Tags: node.js, express

Accord to a book for express3. In the following case, http://localhost:3000/abcd will always print "abc*", even though the next route also matches the pattern.

My question is work in the same way for express4 ?

```
app.get('/abcd', function(req, res) {
    res.send('abcd');
});
app.get('/abc*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('abc*');
});
```

Reversing the order will make it print "abc*":

```
app.get('/abc*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('abc*');
});
app.get('/abcd', function(req, res) {
    res.send('abcd');
});
```

Comment: In both express 3 and  4 versions the first route handler that matches with the requested route wins.

Comment: thanks, it's an old book or an error then. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first route handler that matches the route is the one that gets called.  That's how Express works in all recent versions.  You should generally specify your routes from more specific to less specific and then the more specific will match first and the less specific will catch the rest.

If you want a handler to see all matches and then pass things on to other handlers, you would generally use middleware:

```
// middleware
app.use("/abc*", function(req, res, next) {
    // process request here and either send response or call next()
    // to continue processing with other handlers that also match
    next();
});
```